# native unzipping under wine

Tags: zip, wine, winetricks

Is there a way to extract ZIP-files under wine without resorting to "3rd party applications"?

When running windows natively, ZIP-files can be extracted directly in the explorer. However, the explorer that comes with wine (`wineconsole explorer`), has no idea how to handle ZIP-files. Instead i get an error message:

> There is no Windows program configured to open this type of file

It's of course trivial to just `unzip` the file under linux (without going through wine), however my use-case is a bit more convoluted:

- my system is `Wine-4.0` (Debian/buster)
- a script-application downloads files from the internet and is supposed to unzip them non-interactively

  - on un*x systems (when being run natively) it uses `unzip`
  - in Windows (running natively) it creates a [VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/911796/1169096) that uses the built-in capabilities of Windows to unzip ZIP-files.
- when running the Windows version of the application through wine

  - it cannot access the `unzip` cmdline tools
  - but the VBScript also fails (after installing `wsh57` (the scripting interpreter) via `winetricks`), because wine cannot unzip.
- (I would like to be able to run the application under wine; so even though the application can natively under un*x

So: is there something I can do to my wine installation, to make it extract ZIP-files as if it were on Windows?